# The meaning of "positive" in "real positive content"

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of "positive" in this context? Is it "good"? Is it "clear and definite"?

> The term post-Fordism is used to describe both a relatively durable form of economic organization that happened to emerge after Fordism and a new form of economic organization that actually resolves the crisis tendencies of Fordism. In neither case does the term as such have any **real positive content.** This is why some theorists propose substantive alternatives, such as Toyotism, Fujitsuism, Sonyism, and Gatesism or, again, informational capitalism, the knowledge-based economy, and the network economy. (https://www.britannica.com/topic/Fordism)

Comment: Please cite the source.

Comment: It means "Fordism" and "post-Fordism" both have negative or at best "neutral" connotations - neither of them have *positive* associations. I don't know the relevant economics, but it looks like Fordism is essentially "negative" (partly because it naturally leads to crises), and the best you can say about but post-Fordism is that it addresses that *specific* problem (but it still doesn't have much to commend it).